# Pyodbc with MFA authentication without logging in every time

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, pyodbc

I finally got my Pyodbc authentication working, but every time I run my code it wants to reauthenticate my MFA login (I'm logging into Microsoft SQL Server).

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 
server = 'longstringofstuff,3342'
database = 'ETS'
username ='somecoolguy@somenotsocoolcompany.com'
Authentication='ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+
                      ';SERVER='+server+
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+
                      ';UID='+username+
                      ';AUTHENTICATION='+Authentication
                      )
```

This is obviously annoying and I would like it to stop. Connecting to a Microsoft Azure database FYI.

Comment: Hi @Michael O'Connell, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure SQL database AD MFA authentication, we need login every time for safety consider usually.

But If you're the user who always login and manage your Azure SQL database, please ref this documeng: [Optimize reauthentication prompts and understand session lifetime for Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concepts-azure-multi-factor-authentication-prompts-session-lifetime).

It will help you optimize the frequency of authentication prompts for your users, you can configure Azure AD session lifetime options. Understand the needs of your business and users, and configure settings that provide the best balance for your environment.

HTH.